# Combining an absolute layout into a standard layout

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager

I'm trying to create a simple Java GUI application where I can place ports, switches and antenna's. Then I want to map where the output of a port is conducting to through multiple switches that'll be change in the GUI.

See the picture below is custom created objects (port, cables, switches, and antenna's) overriding `JPanel` containers drawn on a `JFrame` using absolute coordinates.

In Netbeans I created a form and I want to combine the absolute frame and the form together to make one complete form.

[image]

I've done some searching and it all starts with don't use absolute layouts. My question is what layout should I use? I expect to be using 20+ switches, 10+ ports, and even more cables connecting everything which are going to crossover all the other panels (non-Planer).

Can I create a panel using absolute coordinates and then embed it into the form with a different layout manager?

```
package SystemDiagram;

import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;



public class SystemDiagram {

Callbox callBox;    //Callbox
Switch swi;      //Switches
HashMap<String,Cable> cables = new HashMap<>();         //Cables
Antenna downlinkAntenna;
Form control;
JFrame f;
JPanel diagram;

public static void main(String args[]) {

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new SystemDiagram();

        }
    });
}

public SystemDiagram() {
    intializeContainers();
    createElements();
}

private void intializeContainers(){
    control = new Form();   //unused until I can combine it with f JFrame as a JPanel
    diagram = control.getDiagramPanel();//unused was trying to draw callbox, switches, and antenna's on this JPanel of the Netbeans form
    f = new JFrame();   //needs to turn into a JPanel and be added to control Form object
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    f.setSize(1000, 800);
}


private void createElements()
{     
    //output
    callBox = new Callbox("OUT", new Point (0,100));

    cables.put("c1", new Cable("c1"));
    cables.put("c2", new Cable("c2"));
    cables.put("c3", new Cable("c3"));

    callBox.setOutputCable(cables.get("c1"));

    //CA Combiner
    swi = new Switch("1 to 3 Switch", 3, new Point(345, 140),true);// Name, # ouf output ports, top left point of Jpanel, reversed 
    //Output side   
    swi.setOutputCable(1, cables.get("c2"));
    swi.setOutputCable(2, cables.get("c3"));
    //Input side
    swi.setInputCable(cables.get("c1"));
    //Activate Output
    swi.setActiveOutput(2);

    //DL Antenna
    downlinkAntenna = new Antenna("link", new Point(500,320), "spiral", true);
    downlinkAntenna.setOutputCable(cables.get("c3"));



}


private void packComponents()
{
    //Callboxes/Ports
    f.add(callBox.getGraphic());// add callbox graphic (JPanel) to Frame
    f.pack();
    f.add( swi.getGraphic());// add switch graphic (JPanel) to Frame
    f.pack();
    //Cables
    ArrayList<String> cableKeys = new ArrayList<>(cables.keySet());
    for(String key: cableKeys){
        if(cables.get(key).getConnections() == 2)// if a cable is connected on both ends draw its' graphic
        {
            Cable temp = cables.get(key);
            temp.getGraphic().setPoint(0,temp.getFirstConnection().getPortCoordinate((Component)temp));// Sets first point coordinate of cable
            temp.getGraphic().setPoint(1,temp.getSecondConnection().getPortCoordinate((Component)temp));// Sets 2nd point of cable
            f.add(cables.get(key).getGraphic());
            f.pack();
        }
    }
    //Antenna pack
    f.add(downlinkAntenna.getGraphic());// add antenna JPanel to Frame
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: See also [JMCAD](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jmcad/).

Comment: That image (on the left) does not look like components are placed on a panel, but more like a panel that is custom painted. So the best approach might be to use custom painting, and override the preferred size method to return a sensible size. That size could be calculated by adding all the shapes is contains together, then getting the bounds of the final shape. **Returning an appropriate size will then enable the custom painted component to be used with layout managers.**

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: *"I've done some searching and it all starts with don't use absolute layouts. My question is what layout should I use?"* Of course, there are also 'custom layouts' to consider.. Using this approach, the programmer encapsulates the layout logic in the custom layout, the custom layout calculates a sensible preferred size based on the size & position of the components, and the layout manager assigns the container using that layout enough space.

Answer (score 2):

You can compose views together.  For instance, create `JPanel` with [`BorderLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html), add your panel with absolute layout to it with `BorderLayer.CENTER` and add your netbeans generated form as `BorderLayout.LINE_END`.
 Alternately, you could use a [splitter view](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/splitpane.html).

Comment: *"..add your panel with absolute layout to it with `BorderLayer.CENTER`"* ..then `pack()` the top level container to see the absolute layout shrink to 0 size.

Comment: You don't need to use `pack()`.  You could just set the size of the `JFrame`.  Alternately, use `setSize()`, `setMinimumSize()` and `setPreferredSize()` on your `null` layout panel, to prevent `pack()` from shrinking it to nothing.